# Uses of static class members

Tags: c++

In "**The C++ Programming Language**", 4th Ed, $42.2.8 "**thread_local Data**", Stroustrup writes about why static members should be used carefully (with locking) in the context of concurrent programming:

> "... static values used to be popular. They include default values, use counters, caches, free lists, answers to FAQs, and many obscure uses."

What are "free lists"?

Comment: @Mat 2) is still a good question IMO

Comment: 2) all the others

Comment: Thanks for the Wikipedia [free list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) article.

Answer (score 0):

It's opinion based, but my two cents :

- Singletion initialization
- Service registration ( `static int foo = MyServiceRegistry.Register(new FooService());`